# Push pull transformer winding

Tags: transformer, push-pull

This is the first time that I wind a transformer. I follow a tutorial on web and I got this calculations:

Specification:
Vmin=12V , Vmax=15V, Fs= 100kHz, P= 7.5W Core= EP7

Results:
Np= 5 + 5 and Ns= 6.

[image]

According ot the design limitation I need to have make it as simple as possible. Because we gonna use the thick cables for winding due to  highly isolation required and there is no enough space.

[image]

My question is what would happen if I put just one of N=5 at the primary side?
I'm also asking for some good documents for transformer windings if anybody knows.

Regards
Farzaneh

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, no, not for winding. So sorry. Gonna correct it.

Comment: Please tell what you are *actually* doing: what is the isolation requirement, at what frequency range if any (or DC); what is the power requirement, application (e.g. isolated gate driver?), input and output voltages and ranges; and any extenuating requirements like allowable physical size, cost, operating temperature, etc.

Comment: It looks to me that you will need either thinner cable or a bigger core.

Answer (score 1):

> *My question is what would happen if I put just one of N=5 at the
> primary side?*

It depends on how you want to drive the transformer. For instance, in your original design you had a primary winding with a centre-tap and that is always driven with two transistors (usually N-channel MOSFETs) but, if you change to a single primary winding with no centre-tap you are forced down the road of using a half-bridge or H-bridge. Then you need to figure out a few other things like whether you need to operate with resonance or not. It really all depends on how much power throughput you are expecting.

It might also be the case that a flyback circuit is more appropriate but, again, the driving circuit is different again and might only use one transistor.

Comment: Dear @Andy Thanks for your answer. By asking I meant if anybody nows andy pdf or tutorial which can help. I didn't mean to buy anything.

Comment: It still falls into the shopping recommendation category for exactly the same reason as if you paid money for something. It isn't the paying of money that's important here; it's the fact that these types of recommendations are opinion based (another site rule) and links soon become out-of-date or, better stuff becomes available.

Comment: @TimWilliams - If you want to propose a specific approach to what is on-topic, please bring that up on [Meta] and post a proposal for discussion. Making some kind of general complaint on the main site, is off-topic here. To help start you off with some background for your post on Meta (as this was discussed some time ago), [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6512) is the discussion which concluded why book recommendation requests were no longer on-topic. You might find more discussions when you search - I've just given that as a relevant background link. Don't continue *here*.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks, I will do that as well. I was commenting specifically on this answer, and it is my understanding that this comment box under the answer is the correct venue for such purpose.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Re: "*I was commenting specifically on this answer*" (a) It doesn't read that way. (b) If the issue is with site policy, as seems to be the case here (although I guess there might be a misunderstanding - I couldn't find the specific focus of your earlier comment) then it needs to be raised on our [Meta] for discussion. "*it is my understanding that this comment box under the answer is the correct venue for such purpose*" Only if the comment is specific & constructive. Yours seems more of a general complaint about policy. Take all to Meta. Thanks.